# what's the max resolution that I can achieve using xvfb?

Tags: puppeteer, display, xvfb

`xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x24`

Using this command I can get a 1600x1200 screen. But what keeps me from setting it to `xvfb :1 -screen 0 160000x120000x32`? Are there any limitations on the screen size that I can use? Is it limited by amount of CPU and RAM that the virtual screen is gonna use?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation that says anything related to this.

[xvfb documentation link](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find reliable information, i tested with 8k, it works at home (it's bit slow):

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 7680x4320x24" <x11 app>
```

My config:

- CPU: AMD R7 5800H
- RAM: 32 GB
- GPU: RTX 3070 125W (OC to 140W)